# Overflow x and y?

Tags: overflow, css

I have a div set to hide content with `overflow-x` and display (`visible`) content with `overflow-y`.
Unfortunately it's not working how I'd like it to. It adds vertical scroll bars - I assume this is because `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` don't function together.
As far as I'm aware if one overflow is set to hidden, the other gets set to auto.
Is there any other way around this? So I can have the overflow hidden horizontally and displayed (without a scroll) vertically?
Just so there's no confusion here's a fiddle to explain a little more: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/

**edit**
Here is the actual issue I'm having: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/1/
I have a select box, created from divs and jQuery, that ends up going over the div height, causing it to add scroll bars.
It's a shame the overflow function works the way it does because the div's `overflow-x` *must* be hidden, causing the div's `overflow-y` to be auto.

**edit 2**
Please see this new JSFiddle to show exactly why I need the overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/3/
It consists of sliders too, which need to be set to a certain width. And they cannot take up the entire height of the page so I have to limit their height, too.

Comment: The desired behavior (visually) can be achieved by leaving the height of the container as auto. But combining overflow x and y the way you want may not be possible.

Comment: I updated the original fiddle (removed the height) and it worked. Unfortunately when adapting the site I'm working on it didn't. Please see my edit in my question.

Comment: They do function together... just not in certain combinations, as you've found.

Comment: In your particular case, since `overflow-x` is anyway not doing much (since your items are not that wide anyway), you can avoid it altogether and get the correct visual: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/2/

Comment: Did you need `overflow:hidden` because you floated some `span`s?

Comment: @techfoobar Unfortunately I can't afford hiding it as the width is greater than the example. Please see my new example: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/3/

Comment: @VKen It's all based on 'slides' and a drop down box made by divs and spans. Please see this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kwnQk/3/

Comment: You've got a nasty problem there. I suggest a solution not by css, but by javascript (which is wrong most of the time). You'll have to move the contents of your selectbox options out of the `.slide`, when position it using absolute positioning and `.offset()`. Sledgehammer, but seems to be one of the viable solution.
The other way is to make the selectbox options limited in height, and scrollable, so the slide itself doesn't have scrolling.

Comment: Can't understand why this has been marked as a duplicate, considering this question was asked before its 'duplicate'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you can just leave the overflow property to visible and just use padding left and right.
Unless you have images, the text should just get wrapped.

For images, you should look at using children divs with width:100%

Comment: The outter div is set to the screen width. The inner div has a manual width set (for example 500px). This means that because `overflow-x` is set to hidden, `overflow-y` is being reset to auto.

Comment: Please see my edit in my original question.

Comment: Yeah, the simplest solution is to use 1 div with overflow visible.
Then a child div with the width 100% and height auto.
And then perhaps more divs for the red and black parts..

Answer (score 1):

Bad combination, unfortunately. From the documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x:

The computed values of ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ are the same as their specified values, except that some combinations with ‘visible’ are not possible: if one is specified as ‘visible’ and the other is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, then ‘visible’ is set to ‘auto’.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try some **jQuery scroll plugins** for this?

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Comment: I'd like to hide the scroll bar, and have the vertical overflow just be displayed. Even if it goes outside the area.

Answer (score 0):

Try the jquery selectbox plugin, it's great and do exactly what you are trying to:

http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html